# Flutter - TextInputSettingsTile initialValue is not working when the app first loads

Tags: flutter, pub.dev

I am using flutter_settings_screens in order to store data. 
I noticed that by setting the value in the configurations with initialValue property, the value is only displayed but not saved. The user must enter the configurations and press OK to make the changes. 
Why does the package in addition to displaying the data not automatically save the value when the app loads? 
Here below my code:

```
TextInputSettingsTile(
    settingKey: keyServer,
    title: 'Server',
    initialValue: 'server:port'
)
```

Thank you all for the help.